# Z-index doesn't work in chrome but does in firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I've been trying to fix this for a while now but I just don't seem to be able to.

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
ul.tabs {
position: relative;
list-style-type: none;
margin-left: 30px;
}
ul.tabs li {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
z-index: -1;
color: #06E;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
padding: 0.4em 1em 0.4em 1em;
margin-right: 5px;
border: 1px solid #AAA;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
ul.tabs li.active {
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}
.content {
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
margin-top: -1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #AAA;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <a href="#">
    <li class="active">-</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>+</li>
  </a>
</ul>
<div class="content">
  Text
</div>
```

In Firefox this has the wanted behavior (the active (-) tab being above the content div therefore hiding the border underneath it. In Chrome however, this does not happen.

Comment: Yup left out something, fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try settings background to active list element. FF seems to hide anything behind elements with lower z-index, while Chrome does not.

```
ul.tabs li.active {
    background-color: white;
}
```